# Neo4j create edges with multiple labels/properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to neo4j but I am trying to create this simple graph where edges can have multiple labels (or is it properties??)

basically

```
          clicked
User A ---------------------------------------------------------->  item B
       {created at: timestamp, user key: some user specific key}
```

So far I am able to create

```
                     clicked
User A ---------------------------------------------------------->  item B
           {created at: timestamp}



                  clicked
User A ---------------------------------------------------------->  item B
       |    {created at: timestamp}                              ^
       L_________________________________________________________|
```

But instead of two edges, I want to have these two attributes in single edge?
Is that feasible?
Cypher query preferred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can- these are relationship/edge properties. A relationship does not have labels, just a type and properties.

To create the relationship with all properties in one go, you can do

```
MATCH (u:User {name:"A"})
MATCH (i:Item {name:"B"})
CREATE (u)-[r:CLICKED]->(i)
SET r.createdAt=$timestamp, r.userKey=$userkey
```

Or if you already have the relationship and want to add properties to it:

```
MATCH (u:User {name:"A"})
MATCH (i:Item {name:"B"})
MERGE (u)-[r:CLICKED]->(i)
SET r.createdAt=$timestamp, r.userKey=$userkey
```